# How to open the in-game console in Source engine games?

Tags: keyboard-layout

In PC games, [developer console](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Developer_Console) is commonly opened by pressing <kbd>~</kbd> ([tilde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde)) key. The key is commonly placed directly below <kbd>Esc</kbd> key (in my keyboard layout <kbd>§</kbd> is on the place, has no effect). For me the console often doesn't open and I have to rebind keys or look for alternative methods, if supported.

I'm using the [Sámi Extended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#S.C3.A1mi_Extended) (Nordic) keyboard layout:

[image: keyboard layout]

Can this issue be caused by the keyboard layout? How could I open the in-game console?

Comment: You can easily verify it by temporarily setting different keyboard layout with more usual tilde key location, like English.

Comment: Have you tried pressing the `§` key? See [Entering Cheat Codes with International Keyboards](https://www.lifewire.com/cheat-codes-with-international-keyboard-3399944).

Comment: @DavidPostill: Yes, often. Sorry for not mentioning that in the first place. Editing...

Comment: For e.g. Fallout 4, a game that uses the "tilde above the tab" key for the console, I think I recall that the Nordic keyboard uses the `Ø` key. Or was it lower-case `ö`? actually, I am not sure

Comment: The default bound key is not a tilde (`~`) but rather a backtick (<code>`</code>). It might be configured as a dead key on some keyboards. On yours, it looks like shift+ the key left of your backspace.

Comment: @Bob: I've always expected that the <kbd>§</kbd> key ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr0ae.png)) opens the the console by default in games. I don't even know why I've mentioned `~`, may have been an error. The question should be edited for accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to PC Gaming Wiki](https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Engine:Source#Console_doesn.27t_open) the Source engine's default keybind is only compatible with the US keyboard layouts. The recommended solution is to rebind the key in each Source game you play:

> 1. Navigate through your Steam library and open the game's properties.
> 2. Add `-console` to the game's launch options. Start the game.
> 3. Type in the console `bind x toggleconsole` (where <kbd>x</kbd> is the button you want permanently assign to this).